# Why is this SQL IF condition being ignored?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

Have this script:

```
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
BEGIN
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX FtsKeyIndex ON Records([Id])
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ftcatalog AS DEFAULT
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Records
    (
        Description Language 1033
    )   
    KEY INDEX FtsKeyIndex ON ftcatalog
    WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM
END
```

Running it, I get:

> Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be
>   loaded.

Running the following line on its own returns a 0:

```
SELECT FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')
```

Have also tried:

```
IF 1 = (SELECT FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
```

And:

```
IF 1 = (select CAST(FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled') AS bit))
```

Why is my IF statement getting ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `IF` statement isn't being ignored. The error is being reported during *compilation*. Your code never even has a chance to execute.

You need to move any code that relies on this sort of condition into a different scope so that it gets compiled separately:

```
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
BEGIN
  EXEC sp_executesql N'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX FtsKeyIndex ON Records([Id])'
  EXEC sp_executesql N'CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ftcatalog AS DEFAULT'
  EXEC sp_executesql N'CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Records
    (
        Description Language 1033
    )   
    KEY INDEX FtsKeyIndex ON ftcatalog
    WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM'
END
```

As an analogy - in C#, you wouldn't expect to be able to write a method that, given an object of type `X`, first uses reflection to determine whether `X` has a method called `Y` and then, directly afterwards, includes the line `X.Y();`, even if it is inside an `if` block.

Comment: Super insightful! Thank you, Damien.

Comment: As in - didn't even know sql scripts get compiled before being run ;)

Comment: @rothschild86 - yeah. That is part of the problem with the perception of how SQL works. But its an important part of how SQL *can* work so well. The code gets compiled and the optimization phase is insanely good. Which is why we describe SQL as a language where you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. The system is free to rearrange the structure of your query quite freely, provided it provides the same logical results.

Comment: Right on! Thank you for sharing the knowledge!